# Evaluating an integral by changing the order of integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

**Problem:** Evaluate
$$
\int_{1/4}^1 \int_{\sqrt{x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2}\, dy\,dx
$$
by changing the order of integration.

---

I have divided the region into the following three segments:

1: $0.433 \leq y \leq 1/2,\;  1/4 \leq x \leq (1/4 - y^2)^{(1/2)} + 1/2$

2: $1/2 \leq y \leq 1,\; y^2 \leq x \leq 1$

3: $0 \leq y \leq 1/2, (1/4 - y^2)^{(1/2)} + 1/2 \leq x \leq 1$

But solving these three integrals is quite messy. Is there a better way of handling this question?

Answer (score 1):

We first show a property of an antiderivative of $f(x,y) = 1 - (y/x)^2$ with respect to $x$:  $$F(x,y) = \int f(x,y) \, dx = x + \frac{y^2}{x}.$$  Consequently, if $x = y^2$, then $F(y^2,y) = 1+y^2$, and $F(1,y) = 1+y^2$.  We need not concern ourselves with a constant of integration here because the definite integral is invariant with respect to the choice of such a constant so long as that choice is consistent throughout.

Similarly, on the circle $(x-\tfrac{1}{2})^2+y^2 = \tfrac{1}{4}$, it follows that $x^2+y^2 = x$, hence $F(x,y) = 1$.

So define $$R = \left\{(x,y) : (\tfrac{1}{4} \le x \le 1) \cap (\sqrt{x-x^2} \le y \le \sqrt{x})\right\}$$ as the original region of integration.  Then $$\iint_R f \, dy \, dx = \int_{y=\sqrt{3}/4}^{1/2} \int_{x=1/4}^{c(y)} f \, dx \, dy + \int_{y=0}^{1/2} \int_{x=d(y)}^1 f \, dx \, dy + \int_{y=1/2}^1 \int_{x=y^2}^1 f \, dx \, dy,$$ where $c(y) = \tfrac{1}{2}(1 - \sqrt{1-4y^2})$ and $d(y) = \tfrac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{1-4y^2})$.  But since we have already evaluated the antiderivative with respect to the "interesting" points, we have $$\begin{align*} \iint_R f \, dy \, dx &= \int_{y=\sqrt{3}/4}^{1/2} 1 - F(1/4,y) \, dy + \int_{y=0}^{1/2} (1+y^2) - 1 \, dy + \int_{y=1/2}^1 (1+y^2)-(1+y^2) \, dy \\ &= \int_{y=\sqrt{3}/4}^{1/2} \frac{3}{4}-4y^2 \, dy + \left[ \frac{y^3}{3} \right]_{y=0}^{1/2} + 0 \\ &= \left[\frac{3}{4}y - \frac{4}{3}y^3\right]_{y=\sqrt{3}/4}^{1/2} + \frac{1}{24} \\ &= \frac{5}{24} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8} + \frac{1}{24} \\ &= \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{8}. \end{align*}$$

What is interesting is that the slightly different integral $$\int_{x=0}^{1} \int_{y = \sqrt{x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{x}} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx = 0$$ as a direct consequence of the above computation of $F$.